# How to integrate C++ function that can throw the MyException in swig interface file

Tags: c++, perl, swig

I am new to swig,using swig for integrating c++ code to Perl,I have c++ function like 
void s() throw MyException.
How i can integrate the c++ function that can throw the MyException in the swig interface file.How i can called the c++ function in Perl.
Any Help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not entirely set on using swig for wrapping your C++, then maybe have a look at the [exception handling code](http://search.cpan.org/dist/ExtUtils-XSpp/lib/ExtUtils/XSpp/Exception.pm) I wrote for the [ExtUtils::XSpp](http://search.cpan.org/~mbarbon/ExtUtils-XSpp-0.11/lib/ExtUtils/XSpp.pod#Exceptions) tool.

It quite conveniently converts C++ exceptions to Perl exceptions by default. For more fine-grained control, you can declare your exception types to the wrapper and specify how they are supposed to be treated.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394484/how-do-i-propagate-c-exceptions-to-python-in-a-swig-wrapper-library)'s a link that involves Python.
[Here](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIGPlus.html#SWIGPlus_exception_specifications)'s the links to exceptions with C++ from the Swig website.
[Here](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Customization.html#exception)'s a link to exception handling.

Basically you're going to need to set up your *.i file to tell the Perl code how to handle the exceptions.  There's good documentation on the Swig website.  I'm sorry I can't be of more help.  I don't know Perl and have no experience with Swig and Perl.  I'm also having problems with Swig and exceptions.